# YA sci-fi book about a girl who is hired to go to a planet and steal some alien technology

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, young-adult

The book is about a girl who is hired to go to a planet and steal some alien technology. She teams up with a scholar whose goal is to save the technology.

The scholar's dad is in jail.

The girl had a sister who was in a lot of debt on Earth and she was going to be a slave if she didn't pay it back. She had shackles already. I'm feeling like the tech on the planet was in a pyramid.

It's a newish (2017-2018) YA science fiction.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already, although if you could please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories, that'd be cool! Anything might help - for instance, how new is "newish"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. It's [*Unearthed*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25446297-unearthed) by Amie Kauffman and Megan Spooner.

> When Earth intercepts a message from a long-extinct alien race, it seems like the solution the planet has been waiting for. The Undying's advanced technology has the potential to undo environmental damage and turn lives around, and Gaia, their former home planet, is a treasure trove waiting to be uncovered.
>
> For Jules Addison and his fellow scholars, the discovery of an alien culture offers unprecedented opportunity for study... as long as scavengers like Amelia Radcliffe don't loot everything first. Mia and Jules' different reasons for smuggling themselves onto Gaia put them immediately at odds, but after escaping a dangerous confrontation with other scavvers, they form a fragile alliance.
>
> In order to penetrate the Undying temple and reach the tech and information hidden within, the two must decode the ancient race's secrets and survive their traps. But the more they learn about the Undying, the more their presence in the temple seems to be part of a grand design that could spell the end of the human race...

Comment: Don't forget to accept your self-answer in about 34 hours.